# JSON.mapping if "root" attribute has inherit keys

Tags: crystal-lang

I get response in for example next form:

```
resp = "{
  \"response\":
    {\"some\":
      {\"next\":
        {\"user\":
          {\"name\":\"Oleg\"}
        }
      }
    }
}"
```

I use `JSON.mapping` for combine user from JSON

```
struct User
  JSON.mapping(
    f_name: {type: String, key: "name", root: "WHAT.ABOUT.ROOT"}
  )
end
```

how I can use `root` attribute in this case, when I have inherit keys?

```
user = User.from_json(resp)
```

I tried `root: "response.some.next.user"` but it doesn't work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
require "json"
private struct Response
  JSON.mapping(
    result: {type: Result, key: "get_users_response"}
  )  
end

private struct Result
  JSON.mapping(
    client: {type: Client, key: "get_users_result"}
  )
end

struct Client
  JSON.mapping(
    user: {type: User, key: "user"}
  )  
end

struct User
  JSON.mapping(
    id: {type: String, key: "id"},
    f_name: {type: String, key: "first_name"},
    l_name: {type: String, key: "last_name"}
  )
end

resp  = "{\"get_users_response\":{\"get_users_result\":{\"status\":\"Success\",\"error_code\":\"200\",\"user\":{\"id\":\"10\",\"first_name\":\"Oleg\",\"last_name\":\"Sobchuk\"}}}}"

response_container = Response.from_json(resp)
puts response_container
puts response_container.result.client.user
```

it looks a little difficult, but it works https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1k3a

**EDIT**

According to [THIS BENCHMARK](https://github.com/kostya/benchmarks#json) with schema JSON parsing works little faster and use a much less memory.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can only skip over a single level of object nesting using `root`. `"response.some.next.user"` is a valid JSON key, so it could be used as `root`, in a document like

```
{ "response.some.next.user": { "name": "Oleg" } }
```

though that isn't what you are asking for.

There are some examples of using `root` among the Crystal standard library specs, [`spec/std/json/mapping_spec.cr`](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/0.20.4/spec/std/json/mapping_spec.cr).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work [https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1jzt](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1jzt) . Maybe I do something wrong? But it seems like `root` with key `one.two.three` doesn't work.

Comment: `"get_user.get_user_result.user"` isn't a key in that document.